# Moment.JS - Get date from week number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I don't see this in the documentation of moment.js. Maybe I'm skipping over it but I want to convert a week number in a year to a date format.

for example

```
week: number = 13 
year: number = 2017
date: date = // get date format for the first day of that week
```

I'm using moment.js, but I can't find what I want in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com). Is this possible to do? I've found some answers for plain javascript, but since I'm already using moment.js, I figured there might be an easy way to do this

Comment: Depending on how you define what week number a day falls on, just make a Date for 1 Jan 2017 and then add 13*7 days.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
var date = moment('2017').add(13, 'weeks');
```

Note that `moment('2017')` returns January 1st of 2017.

Comment: how do I correctly convert this to the date format? `moment('2017').add(13, 'weeks');` does not provide me with a date type and using `moment(this.dateSelection.otherYear).add(this.dateSelection.otherMonth, "months").toDate();` gives me this result `Mon Jun 01 1970 01:00:02 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)` so the year is not correct, the month is correct.

Comment: This method fails because the start of a given year can fall in any weekday.

Comment: I had same issue with 1970 year. It was also bricking my browser (FF).

What helped me here, was passing full date for moment like:

`let date = moment('2019-01-01).add(13, 'weeks');`

Answer (score 6):

Using startOf('isoweek') you will get the first day of the week.

```
moment('2017').add(13, 'weeks').startOf('week').format('DD MM YYYY'); // "02 04 2017"m, gives you Sunday(last day of the week)

moment('2017').add(13, 'weeks').startOf('isoweek').format('DD MM YYYY');
"27 03 2017"// first day of the week ( gives you Monday)
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to add:
`moment().year(2017).week(13);`

Comment: Much cleaner solution!

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use a [format string](https://momentjs.com/docs/#week-year-week-and-weekday-tokens)

```
var dateLocale = moment(week + " " + year, "ww gggg");
var dateISO = moment(week + " " + year, "WW GGGG");
```

Answer (score 1):

`moment.js` seems to understand expressions produced by the default HTML `input type="week"` element, like: `2022-W26`.

So you can use moment to convert these expressions into dates, like so:

```js
const weekMoment = moment('2022-W26') // week 26 of year 2022
const weekStart = weekMoment.toDate() // Mon Jun 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Like so you do not need to create the date and then add weeks to it. One moment call is enough.

Just another note: for this to work do not forget the pad the week number, e.g: week `1` should be `01`, etc. You should always have two digits to represent the week.